# Lots of exceptions in a simple JavaFX programm that implements a window with a lable and a button

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

I have the classes and fxml files in the same package application and when I try to run one of the controller classes (**AnwendungsController.java**) which calls the fxml file (**Anwendung.fxml**), I get the following errors:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/sciebo/Development/EclipseWorkspace/OOSP4%20(JavaFX)/bin/application/Anwendung.fxml:10

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.AnwendungsController.start(AnwendungsController.java:25)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AnwendungsController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application application.AnwendungsController
```

**AnwendungsController.java:**

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AnwendungsController extends Application {

  @FXML
  public Button closeButton;

  @FXML
  public void handleCloseButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Anwendung.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Benutzerverwaltung");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

**Anwendung.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<GridPane  fx:controller="AnwendungsController.Controller" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center"
    hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="20" right="20" bottom="20" left="20" />
    </padding>
    <Label text="Sie können das System nun verwenden!"
        GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
    <Button text="Abbrechen" fx:id="closeButton" cancelButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCloseButtonAction" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
</GridPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Your `fx:controller` attribute has the wrong value.  The value should reflect the fully qualified name (package.class) of your controller class. Your package is named `application` and your controller class is named `AnwendungsController`.

Instead of:

```
fx:controller="AnwendungsController.Controller"
```

Use:

```
fx:controller="application.AnwendungsController"
```

**Additional Advice**

Additionally, your application class should not also be a controller class as doing so will likely cause you a world of unnecessary pain.  There should be no `@FXML` injected variables in an application class.  See: [Javafx - Can application class be the controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303167/javafx-can-application-class-be-the-controller-class).

**Restructured App**

*application/Anwendung.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<GridPane  fx:controller="application.AnwendungsController"
           xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center"
           hgap="10" vgap="10">
  <padding>
    <Insets top="20" right="20" bottom="20" left="20" />
  </padding>
  <Label text="Sie können das System nun verwenden!"
         GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
  <Button text="Abbrechen" fx:id="closeButton" cancelButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCloseButtonAction" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
</GridPane>
```

*application/AnwendungsApp.java*

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AnwendungsApp extends Application {
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Anwendung.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Benutzerverwaltung");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

*application/AnwendungsController.java*

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AnwendungsController {
  @FXML
  public Button closeButton;

  @FXML
  public void handleCloseButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: [Intellij Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) performs spell checking on FXML as well as inspections which would highlight in red things such as the incorrect `fx:controller` value shown in your original question.  You might need to use the Ultimate edition to get the inspection highlighting (I'm not sure).  Ultimate edition has a free trial.  There are probably other tools which also perform inspections, such as [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) or maybe [netbeans](https://netbeans.org).  From my experience, Idea does a reasonable job.